# c++, omnicppcomplete doesn't show methods for string

Tags: c++, vim, ctags, omnicppcomplete

The problem about `ctags` and `omnicppcomplete` in vim. `Omni` does not show methods of class `"string"`. (I had the same problem with `STL` library. I solved it by downloading `STL` and run `ctags` in this folder then set path the tags file.)
How to solve this problem, run `ctags` in `/usr/include` directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get perfect C/C++/Objective-C code completion, i would recommend you to try [Clang Complete](http://goo.gl/hu0tA).

But if you want to use omnicppcomplete, you need to generate tags for needed class, yes. If you need just "string" class, you can generate tags only for `string.h`, not for a whole `/usr/include`, to make it faster.

By the way, you might want to use plugin [Indexer](http://dmitryfrank.com/articles/vim_project_code_navigation) to get painless automatic tags generation for a whole project(s).

Comment: Clang_Complete is really great! I have switched from omnicppcomplete to Clang_Complete.

Answer (score 0):

I use `tags for STD C++` that hosted in [vim.org](http://www.vim.org), it uses modified `libstdc++` headers for use with `ctags`. And `omni` works well with it.

> This is a slightly modified version of the libstdc++ headers which can be used with ctags. STL, streams and other standard cpp stuff can now be completed with omnicpp complete.

You can download it at [HERE](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2358).

**Note**: The update time(2008-08-26) is so....however, the basic needs are okay. :p